# R: for loop and regular expression to open files

Tags: regex, r, bash

I am trying to imitate a program that I've written in bash, but translating it to R. I have been reading about regular expressions in R and found the command `grep()` but I am not truly sure if it is useful in this case. I am trying to open files that have similar names but different extensions, for instance:

```
for i in i1 i2 i3 ; do 
        program1 $i.txt --parameter1 > $i.docx 
        program2 $i.docx --parameter2 $i.xls > $i.pdf
```

Could you suggest me a way to do this in R? Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your task (I have to admit that I haven't fully understood what the aim is) the commands `list.files()` or `paste()` might be more useful than `grep()`. The latter one you would probably apply onto the output of `list.files()` to filter the correct ones...

Comment: What R code have you written so far? If none, take a look at `list.files`. You can then make use of `grep`.

Comment: I think I was not clear enough. I have files "i1.doc, i1.txt, i2.doc, i2.txt". list.files() is useful to find all the files that end in ".doc" but, how do I tell the program that it should sequentially use "i1.doc with i1.txt", then "i2.doc with i2.txt"?

Comment: I still do not understand what your program actually should do, sorry. If you could write your R code for a specific filepair i1.doc / i1.txt, then one could generalize it for you such, that it can handle several inputs in a loop. But as the command for opening files depends on the file type, such an example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure where you're going with this, but it seems apparent that you need to relate files to each other that have the same name but different extensions.  If they are all in the same folder, you can get the vector of file names with

```
  df <- data.frame(filename = list.files([directory]),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I'll use an arbitrary vector for the example of how to get them related to each other in a single row.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.frame(
  filename = c("f1.doc", "f1.txt", "f2.doc", "f2.txt", "f3.doc", "f4.pdf"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) %>%
  mutate(filetype = tools::file_ext(filename),
         basename = gsub("[.].+$", "", filename)) %>%
  spread(filetype, filename)

  basename    doc    pdf    txt
1       f1 f1.doc   <NA> f1.txt
2       f2 f2.doc   <NA> f2.txt
3       f3 f3.doc   <NA>   <NA>
4       f4   <NA> f4.pdf   <NA>
```